# Basic dimension relationships in a valveless pulsejet engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, propulsion, jet

I'm willing to take my own shot at the construction of a blast supercharged valveless pulsejet, a holy grail among DIY jet enthusiasts.
However, since my idea is not very compatible with the geometry of most popular pulsejet engines, im going to have to build a custom valveless pulsejet first.

To that end, I need to know these basic design priniciples:

1. The ratio of the main exhaust pipe length to intake pipe length
2. The ratio of main exhaust pipe diameter to intake pipe diameter
3. The appropriate amount of flare in the main exhaust pipe
4. Any properties of combustion chamber that have to be kept in a defined relationship to the two pipes

I know there's a remarkable amount of variation in existing designs, therefore im only asking for a rule of a thumb for choosing those parameters.
I would have asked on the pulsejet forum but im still awaiting account activation